# How to get folder windows to display address bars

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Whilst `Ctrl` + `L` works some people want the functionality of having folder windows always display the address bar for quick copying and pasting into terminal. The code below will do this. Please remember to up-vote my solution as there doesn't appear to be one yet when I search for it on these forums:

Open terminal and enter the following code: 
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true` If you want to go back a menu whilst in a folder just press backspace on your keyboard.

Comment: Seriously not a single up-vote? So much for the, "Great," Linux Community. I mean what part of this is great? You penalise new forum members by not allowing them to comment/ask questions and when I find a solution that isn't listed in the forums I get ignored. These forums suck!

Answer (score 0):

Very good solution. Bad community response. Very unhelpful to new members who want to get their reputation up.